# The same three-dimensional scene created by three.js is clear in chrome and not clear in firefox

Tags: javascript, three.js

The same three-dimensional scene created by three.js is clear in chrome and not clear in firefox:

chrome (clear):

[image]

firefox (not clear):

[image]

Comment: Is this an example three.js ? If yes, which one: https://threejs.org/examples/ ? If no, can you post the code that generates the linked images ?

Comment: This question will be closed if you fail to provide a way to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the window zoom level is set to 100% and verify that both renderer.domElements in each browser have the same or similar width/height output from their resize function. Also maybe look at renderer.devicePixelRatio?